# Can't extract text from the dark background using pytesseract

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract(0.3.6), python 3.7, and cv2 to extract data from invoices.  I can read the black text in white background, but could not read white text on a dark background. while getting the OCR text dark background data is skipped, remaining data getting as output. kindly help me to solve this.[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/605gZ.jpg)

sample code

```
def getOcrText(self, filepath):
    filePath = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, filepath[1:])
    f, e = os.path.splitext(filePath)
    outfile = f + ".png"
    if filePath != outfile and not os.path.isfile(outfile):
        try:
            with Image.open(filePath) as im:
                out = im.filter(ImageFilter.DETAIL)
                print (out,'out')
                out.save(outfile)
        except OSError:
            print("cannot convert", filePath)

    imagetext = ''
    imge = cv2.imread(outfile)
    if imge is not None:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(imge, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (18, 18))
        dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations=1)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                               cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        im2 = imge.copy()
        for cnt in contours:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            rect = cv2.rectangle(
                im2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped)
            imagetext += text
    return imagetext
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this includes the code you already tried.

Comment: You need to binarize your image. You could use an adaptive binarization such as otsu, but if all your images are like this then binarizing with a threshold of 190 should do.

Answer (score 0):

To accurately extract the title, you need to

---

1. Upsample
2. Process each column individually
3. Set to page-segmentation-mode to [7](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

---

Upsampling is required for tesseract to recognize the characters accurately. The strokes of each character will become much clear when you upsample the data. Then you need to apply [inverse-binary + OTSU thresholding](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) to make the features more prominent. Since we will be taking each text individually, we set the page-segmentation-mode to "Treat the image as a single text line.".

We start by dividing the image into two main parts: title and rest.

We will divide title into 6 parts and read individually:

|  |
| --- |
| [image] |
| `S.N.` |
| [image] |
| `| DESCRIPTION` |
| [image] |
| `HSN CODE` |
| [image] |
| `|QTY| RATE` |
| [image] |
| `| TOTAL` |

The second part of the image will be:

[image]

For the second part we will be using `binary + OTSU thresholding`(in the first part we used `inverse-binary`), and set the page-segmentation-mode to 6 (Assuming a single uniform block of text.) We will combine the results:

```
S.N. | DESCRIPTION  HSN CODE | QTY | RATE | TOTAL 
01 Utti ncidu ntvolut paturna 5566 20 20.00 400.00
02 Curabiturposuere quam velnibh 8899 24 30.00 720.00
03 Vestibulumquis dolor a feliscongue 1245 4 50.00 200.00
04 Utti ncidu ntvolut paturna 2356 2 60.00 120.00
0S Curabiturposuere quam velnibh 4578 3 70.00 210.00
06 Vestibulumquis dolor a feliscongue 5689 5 50.00 250.00
Freight Charges 500.00

|
SGST @ 9% 216.00
CGST @ 9% 216.00
```

Code:

```py
import re
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("605gZ.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]

start_idx = 0
end_idx = int(w/6) - 5

title = ""

for _ in range(0, 6):
    crp = gry[15:50, start_idx:end_idx]
    (h_crp, w_crp) = crp.shape[:2]
    crp = cv2.resize(crp, (w_crp*5, h_crp*5))
    thr = cv2.threshold(crp, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7")
    txt = re.sub("[0-9]", "", txt)
    txt = re.sub("[a-z]", "", txt)
    title += txt.strip() + " "
    start_idx = end_idx
    end_idx = start_idx + int(w/6) - 5
    # cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

print(title)

rest = gry[50:h, 0:w]
(h_rest, w_rest) = rest.shape[:2]
rest = cv2.resize(rest, (w_rest*5, h_rest*5))
thr = cv2.threshold(rest, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6")
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```